# iOS navigation bar with push without controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to have 2 view controller with a navigation bar, but without the status bar.

How can I push these two controllers? Is it possible without the navigation controller?

Here is one example

[image: Example navigation bar app]

There is no status bar but also with a back button.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code please. See here: www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: push come into existence with navigation controller. However you can hide top navigation bar and add your custom view with back button. Tile etc

Answer (score 0):

Using a `UINavigationController` (giving you the navigation bar and the back button) is a completely separate task from whether the status bar shows or not.

So use a `UINavigationController` to properly and easily push and pop your view controllers as needed.

To hide the status bar, please see [Hide Status Bar In iOS 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146012/hide-status-bar-in-ios-8-app).